# Losing the port number on hitting the invoke button

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx, port

I am accessing this webservice below using the browser (Chrome), not through code. I want to make sure it is working, but I am facing this scenario:

The webservice is accessible using the following URL (notice the port number):

> http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/VirtualDirectoryName1/Service1.asmx

The webservice has one method called **method1**, it takes an integar. Opening the URL above will display the methods in the webservice, clicking on **method1** opens a new page with the following URL (notice the port number):

> http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/VirtualDirectoryName1/Service1.asmx?op=method1

The page contents look like this:

A box where the input should be entered (a number in this case), underneath it is the "**Invoke**" button

When I add a number then hit invoke, a new page opens with this URL (***the port number is missing now***):

> http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/VirtualDirectoryName1/Service1.asmx/method1

This opens "**Page can't be found**" mainly because the port number is missing!

Any idea on how to keep the port number when "Invoke" is being hit?

Thank you.